# How to save the result of a comparison using Django's 'with' template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to create new variable in django template, which will have a value of comparison

```
obj.site.profile.default_role == obj
```

Unfortunately none of this code works:

```
{% with obj.site.profile.default_role==obj as default %}{% endwith %}

{% with default=obj.site.profile.default_role==obj %}{% endwith %}
```

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: Aren't you just trying to do: `{% with default=obj.site.profile.default_role %}`? Why are you trying to compare it to the object itself? It will never be equal.

Comment: ... I assure you, that i now what I need ;) but for the sake of argument, lets assume, that I what to `{% with x==y as boolean_variable %}`

Comment: Why don't you do the comparison in the view, and send the `boolean_variable` to the view?

Comment: @Gocht: I can do that, but I want to know a solution (if it exists), not a workaround ;)

Comment: *`with` adds one or more values to the context for caching and easy access.* It is not ready to evaluate expressions. You should cook values on view not in template as @Gocht explains. To cook values on view is not a workaround ;) Take a look to source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/8047e3666b0b50bb04e6f16c2a4fb21ddfd5713f/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1546

Comment: ... also take a look to https://gist.github.com/aliang/773650 snippet.

Comment: @trikoder_beta   My 5 cents on preparing variables in views, not templates: Daniel Greenfeld, author of "Two scoops of Django" recommended this way: templates - for presentation, not for logics, bring the logics to the views.

Answer (score 4):

`with` can take just a "plain" context variable.

You could try [assignment-tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) instead, passing your params to it.

```
@register.assignment_tag
def boolean_tag(default_role, obj):
    return default_role == obj
```

and in the template

```
{% boolean_tag obj.site.profile.default_role obj as my_check %}
```

This solution is good if variable is used in one template block (like the case of yours, when you try using `with`). If you need variable in several page blocks, adding it to page context with `include` tag is better

Comment: Note: [as of django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/1.9/#assignment-tag), use `simple_tag` instead of `assignment_tag`

Answer (score 3):

`with` tag have no support for value evaluation.

The only possible template-only solution that I can imaging is to split part of html to sub-template and use `{% include %}` tag

```
{% if obj.site.profile.default_role==obj %}
    {% include 'subtemplate.html' with default=True %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'subtemplate.html' with default=False %}
{% endif %}
```