# Define Django variable in statement

Tags: django, if-statement, django-templates

I want to define a variable in my Django template but if I set the variable within the statement I can't call it again. Is there any way to call the variable from the other part of my template? Thank you in advance!

My attemt:

```
{% if a > 1 %}
   {% with "string_1" as var %}
   {% endwith %}
{% elif a < 1%}
   {% with "string_2" as var %}
   {% endwith %}
{% else %}
   {% with "string_3" as var %}
   {% endwith %}
{% endif %}

{% if var='string_1' %}  #here i want to call the variable again
   <p>This is string_1</p>
{%else%}
   <p>This is not string_1</p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how suited this is to your context but try looking at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786214/django-template-conditional-variable-assignment)

Comment: This won't work, because the `{% with %}` tag only sets the value inside the block. The Django template language is designed to discourage complex logic inside the template. What is your real code actually trying to do?

Comment: Use dictionary to solve this issue using filter tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django template conditional variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786214/django-template-conditional-variable-assignment)

Comment: I have complex  and long statements  and I do want use these more times. I mean If i define a variable within the first statement, next time enough to call the variable and check the content of it and do not necessary write the long statement again.