# how to do assignments for variable in django template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to do assignment in Django template tag for this code:

```
{% for ins in ob %}
  {% if ins.heur = 'here' %}
    a==1
    some stuff ..
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if a!=1  %}
  stuff
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can't do that with the Django Template Language (DTL). On the other hand, Jinja2 Template Language will permit this with [`{% set %}`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments).

Comment: So there IS no sulution for now ?

Comment: There is. Check my answer below.

Comment: If your template logic is too simple then the answer below (using the `with` template tag) may help you. Otherwise, Jinja 2 is the only solution. Nevertheless, try, if you can, to put such logic inside your `views.py` to avoid such scenarios.

Comment: @nik_m: another alternative would be to write a very simple custom template tag for assignment, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35621554)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`{% with %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with) template tag.

Example:

```
{% with a=1 %}
    {{ a }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: or create a [custom tag for assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35621554)